# Unable to make index page secure and redirect to login page

Tags: userfrosting

I am using User Frosting V4. I learned about the routing concept.

Now I wanted to make my index page a secure page - which means only logged in users should be able to access the page.

If user is not logged in, he should be redirected  to Sign In page.

I did the following :

I defined my own routing :

```
$app->get('/', 'UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Core\Controller\CoreController:pageIndex')
->add('checkEnvironment')
->setName('index')
->add('authGuard');
```

Now, when I access the site, I get the Exception. It does not redirect to the login page : `account/sign-in`

I get the following error :

```html
UserFrosting Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: UserFrosting\Sprinkle\Account\Authenticate\Exception\AuthExpiredException
File: C:\wamp64\www\UserFrosting_V4\app\sprinkles\account\src\Authenticate\AuthGuard.php
Line: 50
```

Answer (score 2):

It redirects to the sign in page in production mode.

https://github.com/userfrosting/UserFrosting/blob/master/app/.env.example#L4

Set that to `production`

Comment: Works partially.. It now redirects to URL : public/account/sign-in?redirect=%2F 

However, I get the following error upon redirection : Oops, looks like our server might have goofed. If you're an admin, please check your PHP error log.

Error log shows: FileNotFoundException' with message 'The schema 'C:/wamp64/www/UserFrosting_V4/build/bundle.result.json'

Comment: @VarunVerma you need your assets compiled in production mode. https://learn.userfrosting.com/building-pages/assets/compiled-assets#running-the-build-task

Comment: The other thing you can do is leave your overall site mode in development mode, and just override the `settings.displayErrorDetails` setting in your Sprinkle config file.